# How to check if folder in an Amazon S3 bucket is empty? - boto3 python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, bucket

I have an Amazon S3 bucket `my-bucket` and folder `my-folder`.

I want my script to execute different results depending on the existence (or lack thereof) of files with `my-folder`. Thus, I want to check the condition of whether or not `my-folder` is empty and does not contain any files.

How would I go about doing this?

Unfortunately, I've tried searching the documentation and other Stack Overflow posts but could not seem to find anything similar.

Comment: You can list, using `list_objects_v2` for a given prefix and see how many objects start with that prefix.

Comment: Count objects: all_objects = s3.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket="MyBucket", Prefix="myfolder/test/")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can count the number of objects in the prefix:

```py
import boto3

BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket'
FOLDER_NAME = 'my-folder/'

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

count = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=FOLDER_NAME)

print(len(list(count)))
```

Comment: If a prefix contains single object, above method in some accounts returns single element and in other accounts two elements.

case 1: `[s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='mybucket', key='logs/2021/04/03/123.gz')]`
case 2: `[s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='mybucket', key='logs/2021/04/03/123.gz'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='mybucket', key='logs/2021/04/03/')]`

Any idea for this inconsistency?

Comment: @Sid When using the **Create Folder** button in the S3 Management Console, a zero-length object is created with the name of the directory. This forces the directory to 'appear' in listings (even thought directories don't actually exist in Amazon S3). The object with `key='logs/2021/04/03/'` is one of these zero-length objects. If you wish to ignore them, then simply ignore any object whose Key ends with a slash.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. My real concern is in some AWS accounts I get these 'zero-length objects' while in others it is not returned on using `objects.filter()`.

Comment: got it. You mean when `Create folder` button is clicked, only then 'zero-length objects' are created but if folder is created via API then they are not created. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the @john Rotenstein code didn't work for the nested folders, I wrote this piece of code which works like a charm.

```
def check_files_in_s3_folder(bucket_name, folder_name):
    """
    Checks if there is any file in a specified folder within an S3 bucket.

    Parameters:
    - bucket_name: The name of the S3 bucket.
    - folder_name: The name of the folder inside the bucket.

    Returns:
    - True if the folder contains files, False otherwise.
    """
    # Ensure the folder name ends with a slash
    if not folder_name.endswith('/'):
        folder_name += '/'

    # Initialize a session using Amazon S3
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    try:
        # List objects within the specified folder
        response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=folder_name, Delimiter='/')

        # Check if the folder actually contains files directly
        if 'Contents' in response:
            # Ensure there's at least one object directly in the folder
            for obj in response['Contents']:
                if obj['Key'] != folder_name:  # Exclude the folder itself if listed
                    return True
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return False
```